# Compare Groovy array with enum values

Tags: arrays, groovy, enums

I have following Array in groovy:

```
test = [Andrew-PAR, Jackson-CDG, Jilly-MAD, Mike-CDG, Tim-AGP]
```

And also following enum

```
NAME_PLACE("Andrew-PAR, Jackson-CDG, Brian-NY")
```

Getting enum values like `Andrew-PAR, Jackson-CDG, Brian-NY`

What I need is 
*Have to find out the values in enum which are not in the array 'test'
 ie, output will be `'Brian-NY'`

I tried `<enum returned values> - test` to find the output - but it shows the whole value from enum like `Andrew-PAR, Jackson-CDG, Brian-NY`

Code for enum:

```
public enum StudentDetails {
    NAME_PLACE("Andrew-PAR, Jackson-CDG, Brian-NY"),
    NAME_COURSE("TEST1, TEST2"),

    private final String studentdetails

    StudentDetails (String studentdetails) {
        this.studentdetails = studentdetails
    }

    public String getstudent() {
        return studentdetails
    }

}
```

Code for getting enum values:

```
def student = StudentDetails.values().find {
            val.equalsIgnoreCase(it.name())
        } ?.getstudent()
```

Finding difference:

```
def diff = student - test
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public enum StudentDetails {
  NAME_PLACE("Andrew-PAR, Jackson-CDG, Brian-NY"),
  NAME_COURSE("TEST1, TEST2"),

  private final String studentdetails

  StudentDetails (String studentdetails) {
     this.studentdetails = studentdetails
  }

   public String getstudent() {
      return studentdetails
   }

  public String value(){
     return studentdetails

  }

}


def test = ["Andrew-PAR", "Jackson-CDG", "Jilly-MAD", "Mike-CDG", "Tim-AGP"]


println StudentDetails.NAME_PLACE.value().split(",")*.trim()-test
```

Comment: It didn't work for me. seems like enum is not returning any array